# Cómo imprimir los Datos filtrados a Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hola espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy utilizando crystal report para generar un reporte pdf, lo que hace mi aplicación es filtrar lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario seleccione ciertos datos se impriman solo esos y no todos los datos. En si que cuando el usuario filtre datos solo esos datos filtrados aparezcan en el documento de crystal report.

Me dijeron que con estas líneas de código se imprimían los datos filtrados en el crystal report:

```
DataTable Dt = dgvAsistencia.DataSource as DataTable;
        if (Dt != null)
        {
          ReportAsistenciaReport_ Cr = new ReportAsistenciaReport_();
            Cr.SetDataSource(Dt);

           ReporteAsistenciaForm R = new ReporteAsistenciaForm();
            R.crvReportes.ReportSource = Cr;
            R.ShowDialog();
```

El reportViewer que lo llame crvReportes lo tengo en un form llamado ReporteAsistenciaForm y en otra ventana llamada VerAsistencia tengo el `datagridview` con el botón imprimir, que manda el crystal report llamado ReportAsistenciaReport_ no me marca ningun error el código pero al ejecutarlo me aparece lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código con el que muestras los datos?

Comment: cual? el de las opciones de busqueda?

Comment: Sí, el código cuando seleccionas los datos y cómo intentas que se impriman en el pdf.

Comment: vi en internet que habia que agregar este codigo para que los datos a seleccionados se imprimieran en el crystal report pero no hace nada

Comment: Ponlo en la pregunta por favor para que los usuarios lo puedan ver mejor cuando entren a ver la pregunta. Yo lo siento pero con crystal-report no te puedo ayudar ya que no lo he usado nunca. Sin embargo, he comentado para que estuviera la pregunta más completa. Un saludo y suerte! :)

Comment: ok gracias saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué significa exactamente "imprimir"?

Comment: pasar los datos filtrados en el pdf

Comment: @karolprincess modifique la respuesta que te di hace unos día.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que muestras en la pregunta, pareciera como si el sistema no encontrara algún complemento de `Crystal Report` o del `Framework`,

Podrías revisar en tu código el archivo `app.config` o `web.config` y revisar que exista la siguiente línea:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Y si existe que tenga la parte: `sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"`

También tendrías que validar que `Framework` estas usando.

Me avisas si te ayuda mi respuesta, saludos.

**También investigue un poco y al parecer tienes que buscar el:**

`Crystal report Redistributable package` en la página de `SAP`, al parecer la `dll` que te marca error es de `SAP`

Podrías revisar los links:

http://www.sap.com/product/analytics/crystal-reports.html
http://www.sap.com/product/analytics/crystal-visual-studio.html

Otro punto importante es validar que tienes instalado Crystal Report, y las referencias de tu proyecto están apuntando a esa instalación.

**Actualización**

Estuve investigando el error:

```
No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Desde mi punto de vista te falta instalar el complemento que esta en la ruta:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
```

Cuando tu aplicación intenta hacer uso de la `dll` `crdb_adoplus.dll` no la encuentra y por eso truena, no necesariamente la `dll` tiene que estar en las referencias de tu aplicación, si no que puede estar referenciada dentro de otra `dll` que estés usando.

En base a lo que vi en otras paginas dicen lo siguiente: [Da clic para ver la página](http://www.qualityinfosolutions.com/solucion-al-error-no-se-puede-cargar-el-archivo-o-ensamblado-crdb_adoplus-dll-cystal-report-visual-studio/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Otra liga con la misma respuesta](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f29/problema-con-sap-crystal-report-vb-net-2010-a-1085151/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que básicamente es lo mismo que escribí al principio de la respuesta, podrías intentar eso y hacer tus revisiones.  También puedes ver otras alternativas sobre como generar tu reporte sin usar Crystal Report o las dependencias que están fallando.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias am pero es mucho relajo no?

Comment: como que mucho relajo? es lo que estas usando XD El error que muestras es de una DLL de Crystal Report para SAP... o exactamente ¿Qué es lo que estas haciendo?, ¿Cómo pretendes arreglarlo?

Comment: ja lo se XD am entonces es por problemas de SAP?

Comment: No precisamente de SAP sino de una .dll que el sistema no encuentra... Añadiré mas información en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias :) Cristina

Comment: Si lo pudiste arreglar? Excelente :)

Comment: si ya quedo listo je me salvaste la vida

Answer (score 4):

Hola podrías hacer algo como:
[Crystal Reports con Store Procedure](https://pedroavilanu.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/crystal-reports-con-store-procedure-2/)

Y para convertirlo a PDF puedes usar este método

```
public static string ExportToPDF(ReportDocument rpt, string NombreArchivo)
    {
        string vFileName = null;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

        try
        {
            rpt.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            rpt.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;


            vFileName = @"c:\Reporte\" + NombreArchivo;
            if (File.Exists(vFileName))
                File.Delete(vFileName);
            diskOpts.DiskFileName = vFileName;
            rpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = diskOpts;
            rpt.Export();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return vFileName;
    }
```

El query de tu consulta debe ser algo como:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Grupo NombreApellido, FechaHora FROM Tabla" +
If(MyComboBox.SelectedValue == 1)
   strSQL += " WHERE= Grupo + " LIKE '%" + txtBuscar.Text + "%'"
If(MyComboBox.SelectedValue == 2)
   strSQL += " WHERE= NombreApellido + " LIKE '%" + txtBuscar.Text + "%'"
If(MyComboBox.SelectedValue == 3)
   strSQL += " WHERE= FechaHora=@Fecha"
```

Por cada seleccion del `ComboBox` debes armar la query por intermedio de un `if`

El método que recibe la variable `strSQL` puede ser algo como:

```
internal static PersonaAll ObtenerAsistencias(string strSQL)
    {
        PersonaAll _DsPersonas = new PersonaAll();
        using (SqlConnection cn = AD.Conexion.Conectar("default"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(_DsPersonas, "Personas");
            }
        }
        return _DsPersonas;
    }
```

Y lo llamas desde tu botón imprimir:

```
private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportePersonas _reporte = Reporte.ObtenerReportePersonas();
        frmReportePersonas frm = new frmReportePersonas(_reporte);
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Formulario que contiene el reporte:

```
 //No olvidar utilizar este namespace.
 using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
 public partial class frmReportePersonas : Form
 {
        ReportClass Report = null;
        public frmReportePersonas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public frmReportePersonas(ReportClass _report) 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Report = _report; 
        }

        private void frmReportePersonas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report;
        }

    }
```

Claro esta si creates el `DataSet`.

Una recomendación:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            //Resto de código.
        }
```

Al encerrar la declaración del objeto `Connection` entre un bloque `Using` ... `End Using`, nos estaremos asegurando de cerrar la conexión y de destruir los recursos utilizados por el objeto, al finalizar dicho bloque (cuando se ejecute `End Using`). Con ésto no tenemos que estar pendientes de llamar al método `Close` (para cerrar la conexión), ni tampoco al método `Dispose` (para destruir el objeto), por tanto, no es necesario disponer de un procedimiento externo para tales menesteres.

Y en cuanto a llamar al método Open para abrir la conexión, no es necesario efectuar dicha llamada si lo que deseamos es rellenar un objeto `DataTable`, es decir, cuando llamamos al método `Fill` del objeto `SqlDataAdapter`, porque éste objeto se encargará de hacerlo automáticamente, y de cerrar la conexión cuando finalice su trabajo.

Comment: ok gracias por el consejo de la conexión

Comment: @karolprincess agregue la consulta SQL para que filtres según la condición que escojas en el combobox.

Comment: gracias pero ya se filtran mis datos desde el combobox solo necesito plasmar eso filtros en el crystal report o pdf

Comment: @karolprincess Volví a actualizar la respuesta revisala.

Comment: el formulario donde esta el reportViewer tiene q ir ese código?

Comment: @karolprincess Si

Comment: ok en el codigo  q va en el boton imprimir  ReportePersonas _reporte = Reporte.ObtenerReportePersonas();   ReportePersonas es el crystalReport? y Reporte que es?

Comment: @karolprincess Si, ReportePersonas es el rpt y Reporte es la Clase donde tento el método ObtenerReportePersonas(), pero como tu trabajas en una sola capa, ponlo donde mejor te acomodes.

Comment: ok el metodo es  internal static PersonaAll ObtenerAsistencias(string strSQL)????

Comment: Si esta bien PersonaAll es el nombre que le puse a mi dataset

Comment: oh ya y ObtenerReportePersonas que es

Comment: @karolprincess el nombre del método

Comment: ok .............

Answer (score 3):

En general hay dos formas:

1) Filtrar tus datos de tu DataTable antes de asignarlo al cr.SetDataSource ya sea, en con WHERE en tu query, por LINQ, usando el método Filter de un BindingSource.

2) Definiendo Parameters en el reporte y establecerles valores al momento de mandar llamar el reporte:

```
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter", "Hello");
```

Te recomiendo renombrar tu formulario ReporteAsistencia a ReporteAsistenciaForm, y el reporte a ReporteAsistenciaReport para evitar confusiones.

Hecho lo anterior, modifica el constructor del formulario ReporteAsistenciaForm de la siguiente forma:

```
public ReporteAsistenciaForm(ReportClass reporteFiltrado)
{
            InitializeComponent();
            this.crvReportes.ReportSource = reporteFiltrado;
            this.crvReportes.Refresh();
            ...
}
```

Y cambia tu código en VerAsistencia a:

```
...
            ReportAsistenciaReport Cr = new ReportAsistenciaReport();
            Cr.SetDataSource(Dt);            
            ReporteAsistenciaForm frm = new ReporteAsistenciaForm(Cr);
            frm.ShowDialog();
```

Más información en:

[Como Pasar Parametros/Variables a un Crystal Reports](https://inxunxa.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/parametros_crystalreports/)

[Reporte con Parámetros en Crystal Reports (Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyw8yPOVoz0)

**Nota:** Existe otra forma que es modificando el SelectionFormula al momento de mandar el reporte, funciona bien, sin embargo te recomiendo las opciones anteriores.

Comment: y si ya filtre los datos de mi DataTable que hago

Comment: Solo asigna tu DataSet o DataTable con los datos filtrados al reporte con cr.SetDataSource = datosFiltrados;

Comment: ok y como lo asigno? utilize en combobox para que el usuario elija la categoria que busca y en el textbox escribe el dato que busca y filtra en el datagridview el dato que busca y con el boton de pdf quiero que aparezca el dato que eligio el usuario. En el boton del pdf solo tengo esto:   `ReporteAsistencia frm = new ReporteAsistencia();`  `frm.ShowDialog();` donde llamo al crystal report que ya creé

Comment: ¿Cómo filtras el contenido del DataGridView?, usas un BindingSource ¿o haces un query a la base de datos cada que el usuario cambia el comboBox y Textbox que mencionas y asignas dgvAsistencia.DataSource = resultset1 ?

Comment: hago un query a la base de datos, exacto agregue parte del codigo arriba que uso para filtrar datos

Comment: porfa ayudenme! :(

Comment: @karolprincess viste la respuesta de Pedro, indicanos si te ayuda esa información.

Comment: Este video creo que hace lo que necesitas (solo que en VB, no hay mucha diferencia) por favor confirma: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9ne5DWwFik

Comment: hola si ya vi ese video e hice lo mismos pasos pero me marca error en el nombre del reportviewer y no lo he podido solucionar

Comment: @Elenasys no no me ayuda

Comment: @AlejandroMedina eso es exactamente lo que necesito pero en c#

Comment: @karolprincess tu problema actual es que el video que te pasaron resuelve el problema, pero no puedes usarlo pq no sabes traducir vb a c#?

Comment: no, ya lo traduci pero a la hora de mandar a traer un objeto de otro form me marca el error dice q no existe en el contexto actual y no se como resolverlo

Comment: Puedes subir el código actualizado e indicar la línea que te marca error por favor.

Comment: listo! y puse donde me marca error

Comment: crvReportes debe de ser el nombre de tu objeto crystalReportViewer en el que deseas que se muestre el reporte, checa si se llama igual sino reemplazalo por el nombre del objeto correspondiente.

Comment: si es el nombre de crystalReportViewer y ya cheque su nombre y esta bien

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir esa parte de tu proyecto y base de datos para revisarlo?

Comment: @karolprincess ya compartiste lo que comenta Alejandro?

Comment: hola am no es que acabo de ver su comentario pero ahorita lo comparto

Comment: Creo que este es el detalle: te marca error en crvReportes ya que estás haciendo referencia desde la forma VerAsistencia y crvReportes se encuentra en el form ReporteAsistencia del cual aún no has creado una instancia, en tu caso lo agregaría en el constructor.

Comment: @karolprincess ¿Viste la edición que hice a mi respuesta?, creo que así lo resolverás.

Comment: Hola Alejandro ya vi la edición de tu respuesta donde dices que en el formulario ReporteAsistenciaForm esto de public ReporteAsistenciaForm(ReportClass reporteFiltrado)
{ es un metodo o va dentro de  private void ReporteAsistenciaForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { ???

Comment: Es el Constructor de la clase ReporteAsistenciasForm modificado para que permita recibir parámetros https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/k6sa6h87.aspx  http://ejerciciosresueltosdecsharp.blogspot.mx/2014/04/constructores-en-c-sharp.html

Comment: ok listo ya no me marca errores ni nada pero al ejecutarlo me dice que el sistema no pudo encontrar el archivo especificado

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que vi solucionaste tu problema modificando la **App.config**, esto no es muy recomendable ya que esa solución solo te permite correr el proyecto en la PC en la que estás trabajado.

Si en algun momento quieres pasar la aplicación a otra máquina cliente esto no te funcionará.

Lo que tienes que hacer es trabajar con el framework que utiliza Crystal Reports que es el **framework .net 2.0**

Asique si en algun tiempo futuro tienes que hacer una aplicación que la puedan usar varias maquinas conectadas por red, trabaja con un **framework 2.0** a la hora de crear tu proyecto de Windows Forms.

Saludos !